# Skip the Generated on... in Java files using jaxb2 maven plugin

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'd like to get the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to do not write the 'disclaimer':

```
This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.2-hudson-jaxb-ri-2.2-63- 
See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
Generated on: 2011.08.01 at 09:20:43 AM CEST
```

At least the timestamp.

Thank you.

Udo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-no-header` if you use command line source generator or `header='false'` if you use ant.

In the pom, in configuration `<args><arg>-no-header</arg></args>`

Comment: Add to your answer that in the pom, in configuration <args><arg>-no-header</arg></args>

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This site is really excellent!

Answer (score 9):

Just to add, I use Maven and what worked for me was:

```
<arguments>-no-header</arguments>
```

Comment: works with `<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId><artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId><version>1.5</version>`

Answer (score 7):

use "noGeneratedHeaderComments"
example:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</source>
                </sources>      
                <noGeneratedHeaderComments>true</noGeneratedHeaderComments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: you should not generate sources into the source directory. Instead generate them into the target directory. Maven will pickup both.

Comment: @matthiasB you're right the "outputDirectory" parameter should be removed..