# maven-jaxb2-plugin (maven) generated date and time

Tags: maven, configuration, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm trying to remove the generated date and time from files generated with plugin maven-jaxb2-plugin. Is-it possible?

Part of pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>commun-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>my.package.dest</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/wsrest</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/wsrest</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>bindings.xml</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <strict>false</strict>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Begin of a generated file :

```
        //
    // Ce fichier a été généré par l'implémentation de référence JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB), v2.2.6 
    // Voir <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
    // Toute modification apportée à ce fichier sera perdue lors de la recompilation du schéma source. 
    // Généré le : 2014.03.17 à 09:42:08 AM CET 
    //


    package my.package.dest;
...
```

I would like to remove this part :

```
Généré le : 2014.03.17 à 09:42:08 AM CET
```

thanks in advance

Clément

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround describe here : 
[Skip the Generated on... in Java files using jaxb2 maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899256/skip-the-generated-on-in-java-files-using-jaxb2-maven-plugin)

Solution? add in pom.xml, in , theses arguments : `<args><arg>-no-header</arg></args>`

result : no header is generated

Comment: Sorry, under which section should this be located? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

FYI `noFileHeader` configuration parameter is supported from 0.9.0. So you can just do

```
<configuration>
  <noFileHeader>true</noFileHeader>
</configuration>
```

now.

See [controlling the output](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Controllingtheoutput) section in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

@lexicore's answer still works in `0.14.0` version. Simply add `<noFileHeader>true</noFileHeader>` in the configuration section.

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.14.0</version>
<configuration>
    <noFileHeader>true</noFileHeader>
    <schemaLanguage>wsdl</schemaLanguage>
    <generatePackage>[...]</generatePackage>
    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
    <schemas>
        <schema>
            <url>[...]</url>
        </schema>
    </schemas>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of `jaxb2-maven-plugin`, one need to use the following parameter:

```
<noGeneratedHeaderComments>true</noGeneratedHeaderComments>
```